# How to set Additional Properties to boolean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am trying to set [Additional Properties](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#additionalProperties) element into the Open API Schema 3.X but unfortunatel I was not able to find anything in the documentation that help me on it.
I have a Application in Spring boot and it is using Spring doc OAS that relies on Swagger OAS as transitive dependency.
Let me pick some code snippet here:

```
@GetMapping("/{accountId}")
@Operation(summary = "Get account by account id", tags = TAG)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Return a specific account queried by path",
                content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                        schema = @Schema(implementation = AccountDetailsDTO.class)) }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "No accounts found",
                content = @Content) })
public ResponseEntity<AccountDetailsDTO> getAccountDetailsByClientId(@PathVariable("accountId") Integer accountId) { }
```

This attribute is default to true and What I would like to see is as **false** like that below:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want explicitly set the attribute to false you can a TransformationFilter (annoted @Component for Spring) to set additionalProperties to false for each component of you specification if you are using Springfox.

If you are using Springdoc, you can add a OpenApiCustomiser bean, see examples

**Example with Springdoc OpenAPI**

```java
    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser() {
        return openApi -> openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().values().forEach( s -> s.setAdditionalProperties(false));
    }
```

**Example with Springfox framework**

```java
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
public class OpenApiTransformationFilter implements WebMvcOpenApiTransformationFilter
{
    public boolean supports(@NotNull DocumentationType delimiter)
    {
        return SwaggerPluginSupport.pluginDoesApply(delimiter);
    }

    @Override
    public OpenAPI transform(OpenApiTransformationContext<HttpServletRequest> context)
    {
        OpenAPI openApi = context.getSpecification();
        openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().values().forEach(schema -> schema.setAdditionalProperties(false));
        return openApi;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using Spring fox so let me try to figure out how springdoc-openapi implements it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh okay, let me see with springdoc then

Comment: @JanR.Krejci Let me know if my update helped you to resolve your case.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround might be define a dummy class that contains the type information, then use that as the `@Schema#implementation` class in your `@APIResponse`.

```
static class YourTypeMap extends java.util.HashMap<String, YourType> {};
```

Then:

```
@APIResponse(
  responseCode = "200",
  content = @Content(
    mediaType = "application/json", 
    schema = @Schema(implementation = YourTypeMap.class)))
```

**Credits**:  [MikeEdgar](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/issues/423#issuecomment-623379091)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for my purpose because what I need is a additional property as boolean type not a object wrapper. :(