# How generate swagger json with additionalProperties false for object?

Tags: kotlin, swagger, openapi

I have the following object with swagger description:

```
/**
 * Response about request failure
 */
@Schema(description = "Response about request failure")
data class ErrorDtoRs(
        @field:Schema(description = "Error type", maxLength = 64)
        val type: String? = null,
        @field:Schema(description = "Error message", maxLength = 255)
        val message: String?)
```

Swagger json for this object:

```
 "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "ErrorDtoRs": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "maxLength": 64,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Error type"
          },
          "message": {
            "maxLength": 255,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Error message"
          }
        },
        "description": "Response about request failure"
      },
```

How generate swagger json with additionalProperties false for object, like this:

```
 "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "ErrorDtoRs": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": "false",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "maxLength": 64,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Error type"
          },
          "message": {
            "maxLength": 255,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Error message"
          }
        },
        "description": "Response about request failure"
      },
```

Swagger: 2.1.4
OpenApi: 3.0.1

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: You have not specified what library you are using for generating specification, but probably this answer will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489812/how-to-set-additional-properties-to-boolean

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sprindoc-openapi` you can use `GroupedOpenApi` to add a `OpenApiCustomier` and set additional properties to FALSE like this:

```
  @Bean
  public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser() {
    return openApi ->
        openApi
            .getComponents()
            .getSchemas()
            .values()
            .forEach(schema -> schema.setAdditionalProperties(false));
  }


  @Bean
  public GroupedOpenApi coreOpenApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("NAME")
            .pathsToMatch("/**")
            .addOpenApiCustomiser(this.openApiCustomiser())
            .build();
  }
```

This will also prevent the Security Issue ID:`v3-schema-request-object-additionalproperties-true`