# Adding additional properties in Swagger

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I am integrating `Swagger` into my project. I use `springfox` and `open-api 3.0.3.`

I want to add field `additional items` for arrays and `additional properties` for objects in my auto-generated json (swagger auto-generated api-docs). But I can only find this property in `json-schema` written by programmers manually, which is not my case.

Is there any annotation to add to object so `Swagger` could generate this field?

Below is my `SpringFox` configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket postsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("packagename"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaData());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Title")
                .description("description")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Now my array looks like this:

```
"TableArray": {
    "title":"TableArray",
    "type":"array",
    "description": "some info",
    "items": {
        "type": "number"
    }
}
```

and I want it to be like

```
"TableArray": {
    "title":"TableArray",
    "type":"array",
    "description": "some info",
    "items": {
        "type": "number"
    }
    "additionalItems": false
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: OpenAPI 3.0.x versions [do not support `additionalItems`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/#unsupported).

Comment: @Helen thank you, and what about additional properties for objects?

Comment: W/r/t `additionalProperties`, see [How to set Additional Properties to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64489812/113116). Does this help?